# Firestore E-commerce schema structure

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, database-design

I am developing an app that will have 2 main categories, products for pets, which will have some subcategories such as ice cream, toys, accessories, etc. and a second category that will have products for people, with subcategories such as ice cream, salads, and other foods. I have two modeling strategies.

The first one is to create a collection for each group, pets and people, and within this collection, a document for each subcategory and finally a last collection for the products. The second way is to create a collection called shop for example, and inside create documents for pets and people that in turn will have subcollections corresponding to the subcategories, I attach pictures for a better understanding.

[image: Approach 1]

[image: Approach 2]

The reason why I separate the products in each subcategory and not create a `tags` or `categoryId` field is because the app plans to show the products by subcategory and not a list of all the products to be filtered by subcategory, and at the same time this structure helps me to make a pagination for each subcategory in a simpler way.

I would like to know if any of the solutions I propose is a good modeling for my specific case, or if there is a better way to structure the data for these requirements, I would appreciate any opinion and/or suggestion. Thank you very much!

Comment: None of the solutions is better than the other. The best solution is the one that fits your needs. If you're interested, here is another [approach](https://medium.com/p/29f8bcac7acb) that can be used for an e-commerce app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic sounds good to me: if you never have to query across products from multiple categories, it makes sense to store such products in separate collections.